# Is it possible to search for answers with a score under a given value?

Tags: support, search

I'm trying to look up an answer to a question I stumbled upon a while ago. Enter the trusty advanced search. However, I quickly realized searching for [`is:answer score:-2`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer%20score%3A-2) searches for answers with a score over **>=-2**.

Is it possible to narrow a search by either a specific score or a score less than a given value?

Currently, the search behaves somewhat inconsistently: searching for `score:0` searches for *exactly* a score of 0, however any other value is treated as *greater or equal than* the given value, why is this so?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Sure! With dots (more commonly known as the range operator)!

[`is:answer score:..-2`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+score%3A..-2)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Any reason why this isn't covered in the advanced search tips?

Comment: @Nit It's covered on the [messy page with a lot of inline code blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

Comment: Oh, right you are, guess I missed that the last time I was around those parts. Thanks!