# Search my answers with custom sort

Tags: support, search, sorting

I've seen a variety of posts regarding how to search for my own answers (e.g. [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291032/is-it-possible-to-search-for-answers-with-a-score-under-a-given-value) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258415/search-within-my-answers-questions-favorites)) which generally tend to use the [Advanced Search Options](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) and are typically of the form

```
user:me is:answer score:1
```

The returned results are sortable by the following

- relevance
- newest
- votes
- active

  > [image]

Is there any way I can search by any other criteria? Specifically, can I sort the results by something like "length (number of characters) of the post"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com) to sort by other criteria.

Here's [a query that sorts your score:1 answers by post length](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/443247/post-length).

Comment: Keep in mind that SEDE only updates once a week, on monday morning.